# Send Map of query parameters to Spring uriBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, uribuilder

I can't find how to pass a Map of query parameters to uriBuilder even with a method found on Google which explains that we need to pass a LinkedMultiValueMap.

This is my method :

```
public <T> Mono<T> get(String uri, LinkedMultiValueMap params) {
        return this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri(builder -> builder
                        .path(uri)
                        .queryParam(params)
                        .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {
       });
}
```

But I always have the following error :

> queryParam
>   (java.lang.String,
>   Object...)
>   in UriBuilder cannot be applied
>   to
>   (org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap)

It's probably really simple but I can't figured it out :/

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE :**

Finally found the solution a few minutes after sending my request here ! In order to use a map for queryParam I must use .queryParams instead of .queryParam ^^

Comment: great you found the issue by yourself. just write an answer to your questoin or just delete it.